# Configure XDEC X server for running application in true color on remote X client

Tags: x-server, color-management, tru64

I have a DEC Unix v4.0, I want to run application remotely from my Unix, but when i do that, get this error:

> X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  72 (X_PutImage)   Serial number of
>   failed request:  879   Current serial number in output stream:  880

after that i configured my X client to use pseudo color to correct this error, after that my app will run but my app color not showing well

I think if i run my Digital Unix X server in True Color my problem gone without i need to use pseudo color for x client, but i am not familiar with XDEC system.

http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/Tru64/Xdec.1X.html

Comment: This link say about this discuss, but i can't undrestand how can i do: 
https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/support/help/MailArchives/gempak/msg01343.html